# How to get jQuery code completion to work in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, intellisense, code-completion, sublimecodeintel

I am doing some light jQuery based Javascript programming with Sublime Text 2. Is there such a thing as code completion for jQuery?  I've installed SublimeCodeIntel, but getting nothing.

For instance, consider the following:

```
<div id="container">hello</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doStuff() {
    $('#container').html('change it');
}
</script>
```

When I type `$('#container').` I would expect a popup with things like `html`, `val`, etc... to popup.  Has anyone gotten jQuery intellisense to work at all?

P.S.  To be sure, I am not trying to get snippets working, but rather code completion.

Answer (score 5):

Try **package installer** in sublime

search for `jquery` and install.

Answer (score 4):

SublimeCodeIntel should work just fine with jQuery, you just need to tell it where to find it. Check out the docs on [configuring search paths](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#configuring) - basically, you create a `~/.codeintel/config` file, and put something like

```
{
    "JavaScript": {
        "javascriptExtraPaths": ["/path/to/jquery.not-minified.js"]
    }
}
```

in it. Remember to **not** use the minified version of jQuery, as some of the variable names can be changed (I think, don't hold me to it for v2). You also don't have the inline documentation. This file can also be created as `/path/to/project_root/.codeintel/config` if you're using different versions, different plugins, etc. Remember that SublimeCodeIntel can take a little while to index everything, so be patient the first time it runs. I've found it helpful to restart Sublime after indexing is done, just so everything is freshly loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery package for Sublime text might help
https://github.com/mrmartineau/Jquery

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed a jQuery syntax-file (there is one available from the link provided by Srikanth AD) then my [AndyJS2](https://github.com/agibsonsw/AndyJS2) add-in is available via [PackageControl](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community).

AndyJS2 provides completions for both JavaScript and jQuery - use the syntax options by clicking the bottom-right of the ST window to switch between JavaScript and jQuery.

I doubt that it would work well, though, in parallel with SublimeCodeIntel. You can disable this Package, without having to uninstall it, from the Preferences menu, Package Control